# Full export doesn't function

Tags: ag-grid

I have an ag-grid with more than 100s of rows, but, as the screen vicinity is limited, we show about 20+ rows. As you scroll down, the other records were loaded asynchronously.

According to the documentation of ag-grid, it says that "exportDataAsCsv(params): Does the full export.." at this link https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/

But, the problem is that it doesn't export full records unless they were loaded fully onto the grid.

Is there any way to download the records, without scrolling to the end?

I expect that all rows will be exported without reaching the end of the grid

Thanks for reading

Comment: How loaded your rows. Do you call some service that load data when you scroll down? Or you load all data in one call?

Comment: There is a paging mechanism for ag-grid, thus, that is being implemented. Hence, it loads only the number of rows per page and automatically calls the data for the next page ..

Comment: PageNumber: ((params.request.endRow / this.gridOptions.paginationPageSize) - 1)

Comment: Ok, I ask this question for understand you load all data and then use pagination or you implement infinity scroll and data loading. Ok. And how you want that ag-grid to know about all your data and export it if you load only part of the data. The best solution for you is implemented service on backend side for export data to CSV. Or load all data to the grid